# AngularJS, datatables, $q.defer and data reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-datatables

I'm facing an issue in trying to solve correctly the following situation:

When controller loads, it gets data from an API (a Project)
I've on the page 2 datatables that should load only when the first data is loaded (get Project addresses and Project partners) but then I can add items to either addresses or partners and I want to reload that part then.

I did solve it that way but I've the feeling that it's redundant.

```js
Project.findOne({filter:{where:{nr: $stateParams.projectNr}}},function(result){
  $scope.data = result;
  AddressLink.find({filter: {where: {projectId: $scope.data.id}}},function(addresses){
    deferAddresses.resolve(addresses);
  });
});

var deferAddresses = $q.defer();
var deferPartners = $q.defer();
$scope.dtOptions =  DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
  if ($scope.data.id) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    AddressLink.find({filter: {where: {projectId: $scope.data.id}}},function(addresses){
      defer.resolve(addresses);
    });
    return defer.promise;
  } else {
    return deferAddresses.promise;
  }
})

$scope.nested.dtInstance = {}; 
$scope.nested.dtInstance.reloadData(null, false);
```

```html
<table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-instance="nested.dtInstance" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table-striped table-bordered hover" ng-model="dtInstance">
```

I've 2 times the

> AddressLink.find()

Can someone please show me the right way of resolving such a case?
Thanks

Comment: Not completely clear on your situation, but have you considered using [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to wait for all server requests for data to complete? That way, you can process everything at once and you'd probably avoid doubling the `AddressLink` search calls.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried with `$q.all()`, but no no availability as the datatables need to be able to reload themselves...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here... this is what I've done:

```js
var promiseProject = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  Project.findOne({filter:{where:{nr: $stateParams.projectNr}}},function(result){
    resolve(result);
  });
});

$scope.loadAddress = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    promiseProject.then(function(data){
      AddressLink.find({filter: {where: {projectId: data.id}, include: 'address'}},function(addresses){
        defer.resolve(addresses);
      });
    });
    return defer.promise;
  }
  
   $scope.dtOptions =  DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise($scope.loadAddress())
```

This way datatables an be reloaded on their own and meanwhile the datatable part waits on the first "project" promise.

Hoping this can help someone else...